# How to create multiple hyperlinks in single cell of DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Im using datatables to construct a table.
My objective is like table below; with cells like the ContractDetails column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp5nC.png

This is what I am able to do so far...

javascript:

```js
{"data": "contract_details",
              "render": function(data, type, row){
                    if (row.announced === 'Completed') {
                        return '<a href="./contracts/' + data + '">' + data + '</a>' 
                    }
                    else { 
                        return data;
                    }
                }
              }
```

Ajax file (.txt):

```
 {
      "id": "5",
      "announced": "Completed",
      "division": "Food Dept",
      "title": "Food Depts",
      "title_summary": "",
      "area": "Food Dept",
      "contract_details": "os-05-16-00040.asp; os-05-16-00040.asp"
    }
```

Comment: Bump. Still need help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the ajax data itself to be on html format

**Ajax**

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "announced": "Completed",
    "division": "Food Dept",
    "title": "Food Depts",
    "title_summary": "",
    "area": "Food Dept",
    "contract_details": "<a href='./contracts/os-05-16-00040.asp'>os-05-16-00040.asp</a> <a href='./contracts/os-05-16-00040.asp'>os-05-16-00040.asp</a>"
}
```

Or you need to explode the contents of `contract_details`

```
{"data": "contract_details",
              "render": function(data, type, row){
                    if (row.announced === 'Completed') {
                        var contractdetails = row.contract_details;
                        var contractdetailsarray=  contractdetails.split("; ");

                        var ReturnString = "";
                        for(var i=0; i<contractdetailsarray.length; i++){
                            ReturnString += '<a href="./contracts/' + contractdetailsarray[i] + '">' + contractdetailsarray[i]+ '</a> ';
                        }
                        return ReturnString;
                    }
                    else { 
                        return data;
                    }
                }
              }
```

Comment: I got error when trying to format the Ajax file, its a text file. I get invalid JSON response error when I format it like this: "contract_details": "<a href='./contracts/os-05-16-00040.asp'>os-05-16-00040.asp</a>";  "<a href='./contracts/os-05-16-00040.asp'>os-05-16-00040.asp</a>"

Comment: your suggestion for the javascipt part didn't work either. It only display one of the links where are many links in the cell and the cells with just one link displays as 'undefined'

Comment: @WReally I did update the codes. try to use a JSON validator [link](jsonlint.com) to validate the txt.

Comment: Thanks, I am more interested in the javascript solution than ton he JSON, because of end user.

Comment: It is now displaying all the links where are many links in the cell but the cells with just one link still displays as 'undefined'

Comment: @WReally updated again bro, haha my bad, i forgot to assign the variable `i` in the forloop

Comment: Thanks bro, this is what I needed